# Winforms: Location properties got during Layout event of FlowLayoutPanel don't reflect updated layout. Why is this?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, layout, flowlayoutpanel

I am using a *non-automatic* VScrollBar control for a FlowLayoutPanel containing UserControls.

I need to find out whether any of the controls in my FlowLayoutPanel are positioned outside its client area. I want to use this information to determine whether the VScrollBar is visible or not. I've put following code in the FlowLayoutPanel's Layout event handler method:

```
bool lookingForControl = true;
bool controlBelowClientArea = false;
int controlIndex = 0;
int controlBottomPos;
Control[] controlsTemp = new Control[leftFlowLayoutPanel.Controls.Count];
leftFlowLayoutPanel.Controls.CopyTo(controlsTemp, 0);
while (lookingForControl) {
    controlBottomPos = controlsTemp[controlIndex].Bottom +
        controlsTemp[controlIndex].Margin.Bottom;

    debugTextBox.AppendText("Bottom position of control " + controlIndex + 
        ": " + controlBottomPos + "\n");

    if (controlBottomPos > leftFlowLayoutPanel.ClientSize.Height) {
        controlBelowClientArea = true;
        lookingForControl = false;
    }
    controlIndex ++;
    if (controlIndex == leftFlowLayoutPanel.Controls.Count) {
        lookingForControl = false;
    }
}
```

Here is the output to debugTextBox resulting from adding four successive controls to control 2, whose AutoSize property is set to true. Control 2 is contained by leftFlowLayoutPanel and the controls are added to it by clicking a button contained within it:

- **Form has just loaded:**
- Bottom position of control 0: 3
- Bottom position of control 1: 128
- Bottom position of control 2: 253
- **First control added:**
- Bottom position of control 0: 3
- Bottom position of control 1: 128
- Bottom position of control 2: 253
- **Second control added:**
- Bottom position of control 0: 3
- Bottom position of control 1: 226
- Bottom position of control 2: 351
- **Third control added:**
- Bottom position of control 0: 3
- Bottom position of control 1: 324
- Bottom position of control 2: 449
- **Fourth control added:**
- Bottom position of control 0: 3
- Bottom position of control 1: 422
- Bottom position of control 2: 547

After the fourth control is added, one of the control's *bottoms* exceeds the Height of its container's ClientArea (458) and controlBelowClientArea is assigned the value of true.

The problem is clear: The values I get from my FlowLayoutPanel during the Layout Event are one step behind the resulting layout of the form. After I added the fourth control to control 1, it's bottom position should be 520.

The only answer that's occurred to me is that the Layout event happens before all the properties' values are properly set. Perhaps it is called before any built-in layout logic is carried out. If this is the case, is there a more suitable event I could handle?

Comment: This is a built-in feature.  Set the panel's AutoScroll property to True.

Comment: I should have made this clearer: I attempted to use the built-in feature and found it caused too many problems. I only want to use a vertical scroll-bar, for one.

Comment: Well, if you are going to clip controls intentionally then just ensure that they never wider than the panel's ClientSize.Width.  At least that won't be fugly.

Comment: I have some logic for that; the width of the child nodes of leftFlowLayoutPanel are determined by one *guide* control whose width I set to that of the client area on appropriate events. Unfortunately, I would have to use similar code to what I'm attempting now in order to change the width of the first *guide* child control when the vertical bar was shown, causing the width of the client area to decrease.

If I have no luck with my current approach, I might go back to the automatic scrollbars. I had something that half-worked...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get property values which were *up-to-date*, I used the following code to invoke a delegate referring to a method containing my original code, from a Layout event handler method.

```
private void leftFlowLayoutPanel_Layout(object sender, LayoutEventArgs e) {
    if (this.IsHandleCreated) {
        this.BeginInvoke((Action)this.OriginalLayoutCode);
    }
}
```

I used the IsHandleCreated check to avoid a possible InvalidOperationException.

Answer (score 1):

> *The only answer that's occurred to me is that the Layout event happens
>   before all the properties' values are properly set.*

If that is indeed the problem, you could try the following as a workaround.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Sign up for the FlowLayoutPanel Layout event.
            // When that event occurs, run your layout logic
            // using BeginInvoke to give the control a chance
            // to "settle down".
            //

            this.flowLayoutPanel1.Layout += delegate { this.BeginInvoke( ( Action )this.DoYourWorkHere ); };
        }

        void DoYourWorkHere()
        {
            //TODO: do your custom layout logic here.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your suggestion caused the code to run, but not at the required times. However, it led me to this solution:
        private void leftFlowLayoutPanel_Layout(object sender, LayoutEventArgs e) {
            if (this.IsHandleCreated) {
                this.BeginInvoke( ( Action )this.leftFlowPanelScrollBarLogic);
            }
        }
the IsHandleCreated check is used to avoid an InvalidOperationException exception. Thanks!

Comment: If my code helped you find the answer, then how about an up vote?

Answer (score 0):

i try a simple application where i test if a button is in area of FlowLayoutPanel if true it show a textbox message "out", it works:

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                Button btn = new Button();
                flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(btn);
            if((btn.Size.Height + btn.Location.Y) > (flowLayoutPanel1.Size.Height + flowLayoutPanel1.Location.Y))
            {
                textBox1.Text = "out";
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'm afraid my problem is specific to the Layout Event. 

There _are_ Click events that lead to the creation of new controls, and therefore, the resizing of their containers within my FlowLayoutPanel. Unfortunately, the Button that is clicked isn't a member of the same class as my FlowLayoutControl or VScrollBar so I can't use this event.

Comment: but the problem is only that to test if a control is or not on area of flowlayoutControl, you have to do: ctl.Size.Height + ctl.Location.Y > FlowLayoutControl..Size.Height + FlowLayoutControl.Location.Y here i use button click to make a simple application

Comment: Line 8 in my code: controlsTemp[controlIndex].Bottom ...
The bottom property is equivalent to ctl.Location.Y + ctl.Size.Height. 
(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.bottom.aspx)

Comment: you are right but leftFlowLayoutPanel.ClientSize.Height is not equivalent to  FlowLayoutControl..Size.Height + FlowLayoutControl.Location.Y

Comment: I have changed the part of my code starting at line 8 to: controlBottomPos = controlsTemp[controlIndex].Size.Height + controlsTemp[controlIndex].Location.Y + controlsTemp[controlIndex].Margin.Bottom + controlsTemp[controlIndex].Margin.Top;    and part of line 15 to: (controlBottomPos > (leftFlowLayoutPanel.Size.Height + leftFlowLayoutPanel.Location.Y))  The output was the same as with my original code and ControlBelowClientArea wasn't set to true at the right time. 

Thanks for your help, but I've had this problem with every property I've tried using from leftFlowLayoutPanel.Controls.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 while (lookingForControl) {
    controlBottomPos = controlsTemp[controlIndex].Size.Height  +
    controlsTemp[controlIndex].Location.Y ;

    debugTextBox.AppendText("Bottom position of control " + controlIndex + 
        ": " + controlBottomPos + "\n");

    if (controlBottomPos > leftFlowLayoutPanel.Size.Height + leftFlowLayoutPanel.Location.Y) {
        controlBelowClientArea = true;
        lookingForControl = false;
    }
    controlIndex ++;
    if (controlIndex == leftFlowLayoutPanel.Controls.Count) {
        lookingForControl = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: The only difference that I observed when I ran this code is that the output after the form had loaded was: Bottom position of control 0: 1; Bottom position of control 1: 122; Bottom position of control 2: 247. This is clearly because the controls' margins of 2(Bottom), 6(Top) and 6(Top) were excluded from the sum. Again, thank you, but no luck.